# RC circuit with pulse input voltage; finding the time constants

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, pulse, laplace-transform

I've the following circuit:

[image]

> **Question**: What are the time constants of the voltage at node \$\text{Y}_2\$ when the up part of the puls comes and when the down part of the puls comes?

---

**MY WORK:**

The voltage at node \$\text{Y}_2\$ can by using the following analysis:

1. The input voltage (starts at \$t=0\$ at \$8\$ V and is high for \$\frac{1}{20}\$ seconds and turn than back to \$0\$) is given by (in the s-domain using the Lapalce transform):
   $$\text{u}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)=\int_0^\frac{1}{20}8e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=8\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{s}}{20}\right)}{\text{s}}\tag1$$
2. The relation between the voltage at node \$\text{Y}_2\$ and the input voltage is given by:
   $$\frac{\text{u}_{\text{Y}_2}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{u}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{600+\frac{1}{10^{-6}\text{s}}}{600+600+\frac{1}{10^{-6}\text{s}}}=\frac{5000+3\text{s}}{5000+6\text{s}}\tag2$$

So, the voltage at node \$\text{Y}_2\$ is given by:

$$\text{u}_{\text{Y}_2}\left(\text{s}\right)=8\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{s}}{20}\right)}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{5000+3\text{s}}{5000+6\text{s}}\tag3$$

Plotting the function (in the time domain gives):

[image]

So, for finding the time constant (\$\approx63\text{%}\$ of the maximum value) we need to solve:

$$8\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)=\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[8\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{s}}{20}\right)}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{5000+3\text{s}}{5000+6\text{s}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$t\approx0.368223\space\text{ms}\tag4$$

> Am I correct in my analysis or not? Because I also thought about using \$\tau=\text{R}\cdot\text{C}\$ so then we get \$\tau=(600+600)\cdot10^{-6}=1.2\$ miliseconds, is that right or is my previous analysis right? Because I got two different answers

Comment: Just a note. The two R values aren't summed for your cross-check \$\tau\$.

Comment: @jonk Okay, but what is my mistake there?

Comment: What does \$Y_2\$ *see* looking back in? (Assuming you weren't doing all your math and were just trying to take a first-guess at it.)

Comment: @jonk just one resistor of \$600\space\Omega\$, I think :)

Comment: What about your ideal voltage source (pulse) as well as your capacitor? Would \$Y_2\$ only see one of those? Or would it see both? I haven't checked your math analysis, but I think you may have a reasonable answer given my own guess at about where it should be close to without doing the math. (Of course, I could be wrong. I'm just pointing out that my "off the cuff" computation came close to your result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check your calculations, but I can tell you that this question can be solved much easier:

The time constant at Y1 is the time constant of a well known and simple RC circuit, which (google tells us) is T=RC with R=Ri+R1 and thus T is **1.2ms**.

As the voltage potential at Y2 is always exactly half way between V1 and Y1, the resulting voltage at Y2 is always just a (Y-axis) scaled version of the voltage at Y1. **So Y2 must have the same time constant as Y1 which is T=1.2ms.**